# How do I factor out a unit conversion in python

Tags: python

If there is an answer somewhere else, please just link it. I looked for hours.

**Problem**

Write a function so that the main program below can be replaced by the simpler code that calls function mph_and_minutes_to_miles(). Original main program:

```
miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())
hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60.0
miles_traveled = hours_traveled * miles_per_hour

print('Miles: {:f}'.format(miles_traveled))
```

Sample output with inputs: 70.0 100.0
Miles: 116.666667

**MY CODE**

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled):
    miles_per_hour = float(input())
    hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60
    miles_traveled = hours_traveled * miles_per_hour
    return hours_traveled

miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())

print('Miles: {:f}'.format(mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled)))
```

**OUTPUTS**

Testing with inputs: 70.0 100.0

Output differs. See highlights below.

Your output
Miles: 1.666667

Expected output
Miles: 116.666667

Comment: You return `hours_traveled` while it should be `hours_traveled * miles_per_hour`.

Comment: Your comment was extremely helpful. After looking at this and looking at my code I was able to come up with the code that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here it works correctly

```py
# python program to convert mph and minutes to miles

def main():
    print("This program converts mph and minutes to miles\n")

    mph = input("Enter the speed in mph: ")
    minutes = input("Enter the time in minutes: ")

    miles = mph * minutes / 60

    print("The distance is", miles, "miles")


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled):
    hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60
    return hours_traveled * miles_per_hour


miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())

print('Miles: {:f}'.format(mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in the most recent ZyBooks edition:

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled):
    hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60.0
    miles_traveled = hours_traveled * miles_per_hour
    return miles_traveled

miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())

print('Miles: {:f}'.format(mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled)))
```